# Why is not working my horizontal scrolling done programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make horizontal scroll in *TextView* `bRes` programmatically. Reading some answers and tutorials, I've included some settings.

```
bRes.setHorizontallyScrolling(true)
bRes.setMaxLines(1)
bRes.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod())
bRes.setScroller(Scroller(this))
```

I put in the left and right side of *TextView*, small left and arrows black triangles with a click event to make right and left scroll if text width surpasses the view width. The buttons just appears if they has some action to do.

When I set the text in *TextView*, I call this code

```
fun changeRes(t:String){
  bRes.text = t
  bRes.post{ bRes.scrollTo(0,0) }
  val largu = bRes.getPaint().measureText(t)
  bRight.visibility = if (largu > 0.99 * bRes.width) 
          View.VISIBLE  else View.INVISIBLE
  bLeft.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

I've selected put the text excess in the right side, i,e, when the text is wider than TextView, the left black arrow is invisible and the right black triangle is visible.

Well, with this the text disappears completely. If I comment the line

```
bRes.post{ bRes.scrollTo(0,0) }
```

the text appears again, but there is no scroll. I don't get to see the left excess characters. The `bRes.scrollX` value should by 200/300 pixes but is over 1 million!

The first parameter, according documentation, is the number of pixels invisible to left of the *TextView*.

**PS:** I've used exactly the same procedure to program a vertical scroll in another *TextView* and it works very well. I don't use *ScrollView*, I've directly programmed a scrolling in my another *TextView*.

**PS 2:** I've created all my layout dinamically. No XML for layouts.

Somebody has some help for me? 
I have no idea about it, except put the text in *TextView* manually in each change.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of layout are you using? It should not be a LinearLayout, but rather a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout

Comment: [Bruce Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175160/bruce-wayne), I use a RelativeLayout with no widget inside in XML. I've created all widgets dinamically

Answer (score 0):

I've made a workaround that is working very well for me. It's sad that I haven't  found a more direct way to do this:

**a)** I've put 2 triangle arrows inside 2 small buttons to the left and rigth of *TextView*.

**b)** The buttons are visible or not depending if has or not scroll hidden text in its respective direction.

**c)** I've used the event `OnTouchListener` to accept click in the scroll buttons or 20% of *TextView* width nearest to each arrow for getting more hidden text in that direction (I've  made this because the arrows are small and prone to touching in a wrong place.

**d)** I have to keep inside a tag (extra field of the widget) a complete text value of the widget.

**e)** For calculating which text I have to put in a field, I've programmed a heuristic using

```
widget.getPaint().measureText(string)
```

The visual is something like this:

[image: Solution]

**PS:** The ideal isn't using horizontal scroll, but if it is necessary, I think that the above appearance is nice and it is practical for users.  I don't like the *marquee solution* where text moves alone: thinking as user, it's annoying.